# Web page smooth fade in after intro picture fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cross-fade

I have been trying to find the solution here but since I'm pretty new to JavaScript etc. it has been impossible for me to make this work.

So what I need is a firm's LOGO first appearing when entering the website. The logo should fade in but quite quickly - maybe in 500ms.

AND after the logo has been there for 2 seconds, then it should fade away and the actual webpage should fade in.

I just cannot seem to make this work. Can You help me?

Here is the intro page: http://rockworksstudio.fi/index.html

And after 2 seconds or so it should smoothly translate into this page: http://rockworksstudio.fi/index2.html

I really hope that You could be "overly specific". Thank You in advance!

-Tommi

PS. Also IE blocks by default certain kind of code so that would be important to circumvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetb/c3q62m93/

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //After 2000 milliseconds, fade out the overlay. The animation duration is 500 ms.
  $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi again, Mehmet, and thank You for this. I almost got it the way I wanted. Check out this: [link](http://rockworksstudio.fi/) I managed to include a fade-in also to the intro but now the problem is that the main page loads right away in the background and it makes this nasty flashing, so is there an easy way to delay the loading of the main page part? Maybe put it inside a DIV or something but it shouldn't use fade in but merely kind of a delay if that's possible. Can You help still? :) Thank You in advance!  -Tommi

Comment: Of course I can. But I have a few questions to clear things. If you want to fade in the logo only, then the white background must be static, no transforming should happen. Am I right? And when fading out, the white-background can also fade out with the logo?

Comment: Hi and thank You for the quick answer. Appreciated. Actually I use the very same "paper-kind-looking" BG on both the intro and on the main page. It's okay, the smooth crossfade will be just adequate. I already enclosed my main page contents inside a DIV and gave it a Class, so I guess that only adding a delay to it would be enough. Am I right? Just don't know how to do it. My wild guess is that there is a command/parameter called 'delay()' in jQuery :)

Comment: Lets assume the requirements are as I described in the previous comment. Then you need to add a `display: none;` styling (but first delete the lines responsible of the fadeIn effect). Then when the page loads you need to fadeIn the image only, not the table. Since the rest works as expected, I guess you'll be all good then.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. The `display:none;` should go with the logo img. Not the entire overlay

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll try that. No I got this delay in place but the logo "jumps" in kind of a flashing way annoyngly. Is that exactly what you are explaining here that why it does that?

Comment: I am following your updates but you are not completely following me :) There is a script in the head section `$(function(){  //$(document).ready shorthand
  $('.overlay').hide().fadeIn(1000);
 });` You need to get rid of it. And you didn't add a class or style to the logo img yet too.

Comment: Amazing! You're kind of achieving what you are trying to do but for now it's  a mistery for me :) You're not playing it by the book :D

Comment: :D Thanks so much for following me :) I'm fighting here :D I'll try to read those instructions of yours more carefully. I just can quite understand why this Class "wholepage" will not fade-in.

Comment: Have you tried `$(".wholepage").hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);`?

Comment: Oh, no that I haven't tried. I'll try that. Thank You. I almost gave up already :D

Comment: Man :) It seems this is further than what you are trying to do :) After we put the overlay you mentioned a cross-fade effect and I lost you there. If you could explain what exactly are you trying to do, I will try to help you. But not soon this time because I have to work, maybe 6 hours later or so

Comment: Okay thank You. I'm just trying to fade-in the logo and then fade it out after 1-2 secs and at the same time fade-in the main webpage.